# OS X Server Profile Manager 3.1 (Mavericks) - Enrolling fails at "Installing certificate"

Tags: osx-server

OS X Server Profile Manager 3.1 (Mavericks) - Enrolling fails at "Installing certificate"

Fresh install, i use my personal server.mydomain.com for my server in my local network dns. I don't have reverse setup yet but my dns is configured so anyone on my local network looking at the address resolves to the correct address.

Installed the Trust Profile first, all is ok.

Then tried to Enroll my iPad and it say "Verified" on the first profile install screen, I click install, Generating Key, Certificate and the the third step at Installing Profile it fails.

The log on device management is this

```
1::Mar 24 08:06:08.654 [1162] <10.0.1.74> {LogElapsedTime (common.php:74)} Time since script start: 8605us [https://server.mydomain.com/devicemanagement/mdm/mdm_enroll]
1::Mar 24 08:06:08.659 [1162] <10.0.1.74> {require_once (mdm_enroll.php:11)} vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv - POST mdm_enroll
1::Mar 24 08:06:08.825 [1162] <10.0.1.74> {GetMDMACLFromUserAgentHeader (mdm_enroll.php:71)} iOS version 7.1
1::Mar 24 08:06:09.575 [1162] <10.0.1.74> {SendFinalOutput (mdm_enroll.php:85)} Sent Final Output (10460 bytes)
1::Mar 24 08:06:09.575 [1162] <10.0.1.74> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - /devicemanagement/mdm/mdm_enroll
0::Mar 24 08:06:09.576 [1162] <10.0.1.74> {SendFinalOutput (mdm_enroll.php:85)} Completed in 933ms | 200 OK [https://server.mydomain.com/devicemanagement/mdm/mdm_enroll]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never got this to actually work. Apparently the problem is that you need to do a clean install of Mavericks + OS X Server 3 App, and I couldn't install a clean version since I had a lot of data from Mountain Lion + OS X Server 2. In the end wait for the updates to fix it, my issue was fixed with the next major release of Yosemite + OS X Server 4 (actual ver 3.5)